# Is this the correct way to ask? "within what time should I send the mail"

Tags: word-choice, slang, questions

I will explain the scenario. My manager asked me to send a mail with some documents attached and to send it as soon as possible. Now, I want to know how soon exactly. So should I ask "Within what time should I send the mail?" or "Before how many hours should I send you the mail?"

Both of those sentences sound awfully wrong. So is there a better way to frame that question?

Comment: As soon as possible, surely.

Comment: Don’t ask how soon to send it. You already know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Do you have a deadline for this please?" See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deadline

Or "By what time do you need this please?"

Comment: Sure, that conveys the message I want to ask. But not the exact line I'm looking for. I want to see if there is a proper and clear sentence similar to the one I came up with - "Before how long do you need the mail" something like that but with a proper meaning, word choice and grammar. If I don't find anything else I will be using this line. Thanks

Comment: Understood. I have made another suggestion in my edited answer.